# How do I check if image is taken using ionic 2 angular 2

Tags: angular, camera, ionic2

I have an app that requests the user to take a picture (though optionally), I want to inform the user through an alert that he has not taken a picture.

I stored the image in a local storage, to be overwritten if another picture is taken and also cleared when the image is sent to my database.

I am able to capture an image and send to my database, but informing the user who does not want to take a picture is my challenge.

I have tried but to no avail, here is the excerpt of my code

```
goToAppreciation(){
this.storage.get('image').then((value) => {
var imageTaken = value 
this.picture = imageTaken});

  if(this.picture==""){
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Please Confirm ',
    message: 'Do you want to proceed without taken picture?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'No',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Yes clicked');
        // proceed without  image
        }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();
} else{
// proceed to upload the image
}
```

Comment: I am a little unclear about what you are asking.  If person says 'No' I do not want to take a picture then you wish to continue along.  If the person says 'Yes' I want to take a picture but doesn't you want to warn them?

Comment: the challenge is I want to show an alert based on the image capture, I can handle the action that follows